# .profile configured, no error message, but no change

Tags: terminal, imac, path

New to editing my .profile, so please bear with me if my question seems somewhat trivial.

I downloaded software to convert a proprietary data to ASCII, the software being from Trimble. Then I did the following:

```
cd /Users/my_iMac
mkdir runpkr00
cd runpkr00/
cp ~/Downloads/runpkr00-MountainLion-i386-5-4.40 .
vi ~/.profile
```

In .profile

```
export PATH="/Users/my_iMac/runpkr00:$PATH"
```

Then back out...

```
source ~/.profile
```

When I begin typing runpkr and then tab, it is recognised, then trying to convert a .T02 file (in the correct directory), the command is executed and doesn't return an error message, but doesn't convert the files either. After reading about setting variables in the .profile I'm still a bit confused about where programs should be stored (/usr/local/bin or /usr/bin/ or simply /bin/) and whether the program should be stored in either one of these three directories.

Answer (score 1):

The following is an overview of the directories that you mentioned.

```
/bin  user utilities fundamental to both single-user and multi-user environments

/usr/bin  common utilities, programming tools, and applications

/usr/local/bin  executables, libraries, etc. not included by the basic operating system
```

Since your application isn't delivered by a package, I would leave it in your home folder.

Comment: So that would mean leave it where it is (/Users/my_iMac)? If so, then it does not explain why I can't use this application. I think 'Im going wrong somewhere...

Comment: What output do you get from this command `type runpkr00-MountainLion-i386-5-4.40`?

Comment: runpkr00-MountainLion-i386-5-4.40 is hashed (/Users/my_iMac/runpkr00/runpkr00-MountainLion-i386-5-4.40)

Comment: You did a great job! The program has been added to your PATH variabIe. I believe your problem is with the program's syntax. Is there an online manual?

Comment: I had it working before, stupid thing is the runpkr program was on my Desktop, and I deleted it. It should work, but my setup is wrong :/

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, was correctly installed but I missed a parameter in the command line when executing the program. Thanks for the description anyway!